# Difference between TargetType="controlType" and TargetType="{x:Type controlType}"

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, targettype

In WPF you can set the `TargetType` to either the name of the type or you can set it to `{x:Type nameOfType}`.

Does anyone know what the difference is?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nothing. Since the property type is `Type`, the XAML parser knows to try and convert whatever you supply to a `Type`. In other scenarios, the property type might be less specific (eg. `Object`), and that's where you need the markup extension, otherwise the XAML parser will just interpret your value as a `String`.

Answer (score 16):

I have recently encountered a situation which shows that `x:Type` **is different** from `TypeName-as-String`.

From my experience -

**`x:Type` considers the strong name or the version of the assembly but not `TypeName-as-String`.**

I have explained about my scenario and other details in my blog here -

[Importance of specifying AncestorType with x:Type in RelativeSourceBinding](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2012/02/03/importance-of-specifying-ancestortype-with-x-type-in-relativesourcebinding.aspx)

Apart from this, there is also difference in how WPF infers the type. For *`x:Type`* `TypeExtension` is used, whereas for *`TypeName-as-String`* `FrameworkElementFactory` is used.

As per MSDN - [x:Type Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx)

> **Type Properties That Support Typename-as-String**
>
> WPF supports techniques that enable specifying the value of some
>   properties of type Type without requiring an `x:Type` markup extension
>   usage. Instead, you can specify the value as a string that names the
>   type. Examples of this are `ControlTemplate.TargetType` and
>   `Style.TargetType`. Support for this behavior is not provided through
>   either type converters or markup extensions. Instead, this is a
>   deferral behavior implemented through `FrameworkElementFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the real difference described above, using `{x:Type NameOfType}` obviously will be highlighted differently in your IDE and makes it stand out and spot right away (as opposed to a regular string). So this is my personal preference.