# What is the difference for TargetType="{x:Type Button}" and TargetType="Button"?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

What is the difference for

```
TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
```

and

```
TargetType="Button"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when to use {x:Type …}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167536/when-to-use-xtype)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The XAML designer applies inbuilt type converters that convert the string value "Button" to `System.Type` which is `Button` , which makes it seem like there is no practical difference.

However one should practise to use the explicit Type specification using `x:Type`.

Explicit `Type` specification is required is when we inherit `Styles` using `BasedOn`, there implicit string `Type` wont work.

e.g.

This would work

```
 BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
```

But not this...

```
 BasedOn="{StaticResource Button}"
```

as here it would try to search a resource with Key "Button". But in the `x:Type` specification, as we already specified explicit `Button` `Type` the search of the static resource would be happen for the `Style` which is targetted for a `Button`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but what do you mean by explicitly for a style?

Comment: explicit is object of `Type` `{x:Type Button}` and implicit means string `"Button"`.