# Content Presenter in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was under the impression that a ContentPresenter would display the content of a Control.

However, if I use this :

```
<Button  Content="Remove table">
    <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
     <Grid x:Name="grid" >
      <Border x:Name="border"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  >
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Border>
     </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

No text actually gets displayed.
Where am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the TargetType="Button" will show the text you are expecting.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
```

**Reference:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx

Comment: What is the rule for "Button" VS  "{x:Type Button}" ?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558287/what-is-the-difference-for-targettype-xtype-button-and-targettype-button