# WPF Difference between TargetType=" " and "{x:Type}"

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, targettype

I'm learning WPF and I don't understand what's the difference between e.g. TargetType = "TextBlock" and TargetType = "{x:Type TextBlock}".

Comment: Already asked and solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558287/what-is-the-difference-for-targettype-xtype-button-and-targettype-button