# Style TargetType property question

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles

What is the difference between the following TargetType specifications?

1.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" ...
```

2.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" ...
```

It seems the both works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between TargetType="controlType" and TargetType="{x:Type controlType}"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085730/difference-between-targettype-controltype-and-targettype-xtype-controltype)

Comment: sorry, i searched for an answer but found nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the `Type` markup extension creates an instance of `Type` specified by the given string, i.e. `Button`.

In the second example, the type converter associated with the `TargetType` property converts the string `"Button"` into the required `Type`.

*Both give exactly the same result*. Notably, in Silverlight the `Type` markup extension does not exist so (2) is only possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for poking such an old thread but I feel it's worth it. I have recently encountered a situation which shows that *`x:Type`* is different from *`TypeName-as-String`*. From my experience -

***x:Type* considers the strong name or the version of the assembly but not *TypeName-as-String*.**

I have explained about my scenario and other details in my blog here -

http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2012/02/03/importance-of-specifying-ancestortype-with-x-type-in-relativesourcebinding.aspx

Apart from this, there is also difference in how WPF infers the type. For *x:Type* TypeExtension is used, whereas for *TypeName-as-String* FrameworkElementFactory is used.

As per MSDN -

> Type Properties That Support Typename-as-String
>
> WPF supports techniques that enable specifying the value of some
>   properties of type Type without requiring an x:Type markup extension
>   usage. Instead, you can specify the value as a string that names the
>   type. Examples of this are ControlTemplate.TargetType and
>   Style.TargetType. Support for this behavior is not provided through
>   either type converters or markup extensions. Instead, this is a
>   deferral behavior implemented through FrameworkElementFactory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx