# WPF - Is there a way to target an element type in a ControlTemplate's trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate, targettype

I have the following ControlTemplate defined:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="buttonBorder">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtLabel" Grid.Column="0">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </TextBlock>
            <Canvas x:Name="reschedule" Grid.Column="1">
                <Path x:Name="path1" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path2" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path3" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path4" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path5" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path6" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path7" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path8" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path9" ... />
                <Path x:Name="path10" ... />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
            <Setter TargetName="txtLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Right now the default `TextBlock` `Foreground` and `Path` `Fill` properties have been set to `White`. When the button is disabled I want to set those properties to `Gray`. Right now it works for the `TextBlock` and I can make it work for the `Path`s too by targetting each of their names, but is there a way to target all the `Path` elements by type? Something like:

```
<Setter TargetType="Path" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
```

I've tried adding the following trigger to the `Border` element's style but it doesn't work:

```
<Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Path">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

Comment: yes use in your style `TargetType="{x:Type Path}"`, this should target all elements of type `Path`. HTH

Comment: It seems like triggers not defined within a style block don't have the `TargetType` property

Comment: in the question you have this xaml `<Border.Style><Style TargetType="Border"><Style.Resources>` _and here is where you place your_ **TargetType="{x:Type Path}"** . So instead of using `<Style TargetType="Path"` use `TargetType="{x:Type Path}"`. BTW place this style outside of the template definition otherwise it will not be evaluated. HTH

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks! I thought `TargetType="Path"` and `TargetType="{x:Type Path}"` were identical...? It seems to work either way. What did work was that I had to take my style out of the template definition and then reference the style by key.

Comment: fantastic if you want I can create an answer and explain to you the difference between `TargetType="Path"` and `TargetType="{x:Type Path}"`?

Comment: Yea that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this trick:

Create a proxy control for `Binding`:

```
<Control x:Name="Proxy" Background="White" />
```

And use in `Path` binding like this:

```
<Path x:Name="path1" Fill="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=Proxy}" Data="..." />
```

When you're in the Trigger set the color for the Proxy, his tucked up all the Path's.

Or instead of the binding Proxy, you can use any existing controls, such `TextBlock`.

Full example:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border x:Name="buttonBorder">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="txtLabel" Grid.Column="0">                        
                <ContentPresenter />
            </TextBlock>

            <Control x:Name="Proxy" Background="White" /> 

            <Canvas x:Name="reschedule" Grid.Column="1">
                <Path x:Name="path1" Fill="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=Proxy}" Data="..." />
                <Path x:Name="path2" Fill="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=Proxy}" Data="..." />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
            <Setter TargetName="txtLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter TargetName="Proxy" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I ended up going with this solution but instead of creating a proxy control I just set the `Path` `Fill` property to `Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=txtLabel}"` since the `TextBlock` already has the same behavior as the proxy

Answer (score 1):

1) Using **Canvas Resource** to store path style.

Please see **`<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">`** and **`<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">`**

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="buttonBorder">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtLabel" Grid.Column="0">
            <ContentPresenter/>
                </TextBlock>                                       
                <Canvas x:Name="reschedule" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Path x:Name="path1" Data="M 0 0 L 0 10 L 10 10 Z"/>
                    <Path x:Name="path2"  Data="M 0 0 L 0 10 L 10 10 Z" />                     
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                            
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
                <Setter TargetName="reschedule" Property="Style">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Style.Resources>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>                                       
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">                 
                <Setter TargetName="reschedule" Property="Style">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Style.Resources>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>       
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="40" Width="40" Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
    <Button Height="40" Width="40" Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" IsEnabled="True"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

2) Using **Canvas Tag**

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="buttonBorder">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtLabel" Grid.Column="0">
            <ContentPresenter/>
                </TextBlock>
                <Canvas x:Name="reschedule" Tag="Red" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Path x:Name="path1" Fill="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}" Data="M 0 0 L 0 10 L 10 10 Z"/>
                    <Path x:Name="path2" Fill="{Binding Path=Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}"  Data="M 0 0 L 0 10 L 10 10 Z" />
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
                <Setter TargetName="reschedule" Property="Tag" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="40" Width="40" Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
    <Button Height="40" Width="40" Margin="10" Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}" IsEnabled="True"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your style wasn't working is because it was inside of the template.
To get it to work you need to apply your Style outside of your template. Not sure why it's done this way, might be something to do with how styles are processed in xaml.
Another matter to discuss is the significance of style definition:
`<Style TargetType="Path">` will not be the same as the `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">`.
The first one will give you an error if defined in the resources tag, as it will need a key by which you can reference the style explicitly in all your target types.
The latter is assigned to every control of type `Path`, so if you define it inside `DockPanel` then every `Path` inside of that `DockPanel` will be affected by the style, however if the `Path` is outside of the `DockPanel` no styling will be applied, unless explicitly defined elsewhere, this style is applied to controls implicitly.
HTH

Comment: hm... after looking at some other explanations of why `TargetType="Path"` is different than `TargetType="{x:Type Path}"` it seems like there's generally no difference except for situations such as `RelativeSource` bindings and `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"`. See **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558287/what-is-the-difference-for-targettype-xtype-button-and-targettype-button)** and **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085730/difference-between-targettype-controltype-and-targettype-xtype-controltype)**