# Can I make something like variables in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm noob as far XAML goes. So please bear with me if I ask stupid questions please. I will try to explain what I want so if you can, please help me. Atm I have code with alot of `TextBlocks`, let's say 20, and I want to change in all of them text to 0, `Text = "0"`. atm I do all that manualy and I feel stupid. In C# I could just do

```
private string name = "0";
```

and in whole program every name will be "0"
can I do that in XAML so I wont have to do manualy every name. Same question is for Margin etc.

Thanks, and sorry if I explained poorly.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to handle your request.  You are probably looking for [Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx).

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType='TextBox'>
    <Setter Property='Text'
            Value='Example' />
    <Setter Property='Margin' Value='10,5'/>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
  </StackPanel>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

[Edit]
The other approach is the one offered by DevEstacion.  In the resources section of XAML declare the variable value.  Then use the StaticResource markup extension to apply the value to the element property.

Comment: Also `TargetType={x:Type TextBlock}` can be used. As type-As-string has additional overhead, which is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9128422/2029607).

Comment: I like how styles feel, I have read documentation on MSDN. So far I have worked only with basic XAML code. Whatever I try to do it say "Property content is set more than once". I guess that is super noobish question, but could you tell me how to implement style in my code.

Comment: Styles are typically uses in XAML, less so in code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add a reference in the XAML file.

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Create the object like this

```
<sys:String x:Key="textboxValue">0</sys:String>
```

And use it in your objects within the xaml file.

```
<TextBox Text="{StaticResource textboxValue}" />
```

Answer (score -3):

You can assign the vale on the textbox's Loaded event in the code behind.

Comment: I'm reading the context / intent of his question and not just the subject. As a result, my answer is still valid based on the context of his question. "So I won't have to do manually every time". Now give me back my points that you deducted.